# Reflection Recursive through object with list(of)

Tags: vb.net, class, reflection

Wanting to use Reflection to get object Name and value. I am able to get through DocumentConfig class but unable to get Fields.  Doesn't want to identify the gettype as a list(of) either.  If force into the list(of) returns message fielditems is not member of DocumentConfig class.

```
Public Class MyDocuments
Public Class DocumentConfig
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Fields() As New List(Of FieldItems)
End Class
Public Class FieldItems
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
End Class
End Class

Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim Document As New List(Of FieldItems)
    Document.Add(New FieldItems With {.Name = "Invoice"})
    Document.Add(New FieldItems With {.Name = "Statement"})
    Document.Add(New FieldItems With {.Name = "Reminder"})
End Sub
Public Sub DisplayAll(ByVal Someobject As DocumentConfig)
        Dim _type As Type = Someobject.GetType()
        Console.WriteLine(_type.ToString())
        Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance
        Dim properties() As PropertyInfo = _type.GetProperties(flags)
        For Each _property As PropertyInfo In properties
            Dim valuetype = _property.GetType()
            If [_property].PropertyType = GetType(String) OrElse [_property].PropertyType = GetType(Integer) OrElse [_property].PropertyType = GetType(Boolean) then
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + _property.Name + ", Value: " + _property.GetValue(Someobject, Nothing))
            ElseIf _property.PropertyType = GetType(List(Of)) Then
                Dim list = [_property].GetValue(Someobject, Nothing)
                For Each item In list
                    DisplayAll(item)
                Next
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + _property.Name)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `List(Of)` and `List(Of FieldItems)` are actually two different types, just like `List(Of FieldItems)` and `List(Of String)` would be two different types.

When you call `GetType(List(Of))` it's returning a `Type` representing the base, generic [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) class (which is usually written as `List<T>`, "T" being a placeholder for the type that will be used). But the property `Fields` that you're looking for for is of type `List<FieldItems>`, not `List<T>`.

If you change your code to

```
ElseIf _property.PropertyType = GetType(List(Of FieldItems)) Then
```

then is should work.

On the other hand, if you need your code to be able to work for any type of `List<T>`, you can use `Type.IsGenericType` to tell if a `Type` is a generic type, and then use `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` to find out which generic type it is. The below code, for example, would return `True` in an if statement:

```
(New List(Of String)).GetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition = GetType(List(Of))
```

---

One other note, it's not usual to declare your properties with parentheses like you have.

```
Public Property Fields() As New List(Of FieldItems)
```

should just be

```
Public Property Fields As New List(Of FieldItems)
```

Putting parentheses on a variable like that in VB.NET usually means you're declaring an array, for example: `Dim foo() As String` creates an array of strings. It's not actually declaring an array in the way you're using them, but they're misleading and unnecessary.

Comment: Adjusting to List(of fielditems) works.. thanks.  However once attempting to DisplayAll(item) receiving error 'unable to case object type 'fielditems' to DocumentConfig.  Suggestions?

Comment: By changing Someobject As DocumentConfig to just Object corrected the error I was receiving.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Great! Please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then.